# How to add commas format in number after page load using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one page which is having bank funds summary details and i am getting all these value from API. These values are not formatted for example like 50000.3645656.

So here is my page structure given below

```
<span class="format">50000.3645656</span>
<span class="format">50000.3645656</span>
<span class="format">50000.3645656</span>
<span class="format">50000.3645656</span>
<span class="format">50000.3645656</span>
```

So what i want exactly is , I want to format all these value with comma formated with two decimal point like 50,000.36.

How can i do this after page load using jquery and css class format in jquery method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this using pure CSS.

However, you could use a JavaScript function to add commas for you.

I have used this one in the past:

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
   nStr += '';
   var x = nStr.split('.');
   var x1 = x[0];
   var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
   var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
   while (rgx.test(x1)) {
      x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
   }
   return x1 + x2;
}
```

[**Reference**](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html)

And then do your jquery:

```
$(function(){
   $(".format").each(function(c, obj){
      $(obj).text(addCommas(parseFloat($(obj).text()).toFixed(2)));
   });
});
```

[**JSfiddle Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ls9r/2/):

Comment: You forgot to change it to 2 decimal places as well.

Comment: +1: Now does everything asked. Why oh why didn't they add a nice string.format (C# style) to the javascript libs :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative why not using a tiny library that does the job well:

http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
    var input = '55021.1231';
    var parts = input.split('.');
    var part1 = parts[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    var part2 = parseFloat('0.'+parts[1]).toFixed(2);
    part2=part2.split('.');
    alert(part1 + '.' + part2[1]);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tPxr7/19/)**

Comment: Not sure why this work, but it works :) Can you please explain your RegEx? Can you also make it round to 2 decimal places as requested as SO?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add split code. will make more sense now.