# How to format input type numbers after page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I have a dynamic table with input fields with type = number, I want the `jquery` to format all the input on page load with `type = numbers` to number format (1,000,000) for 3 value place then it will add a comma.

I have tried using number.js and google visualization and jquery number format but I cant find the one that is working properly. I want the simplest way to do it.

The document should load with the inputs type numbers formatted, I tried so many codes but none is working :((

i also tried this one [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477805/how-to-add-commas-format-in-number-after-page-load-using-jquery)

Comment: after page loading finished, u can do this,or u can format on server side.

Comment: You can't format the value in [an input with `type="number"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html). The implementation of the control is based on the browser/OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution I have used before, it uses regular expressions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        $(".format").each(function(){
            var str = $(this).text().split('.');
            str[0] = str[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
            $(this).text(str[0] + "." + str[1]); 
        });
    });
});
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) post for an explanation of the regex used.

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work because a) for input elements, you'd use `val()` rather than `text()` and b) the type of the input is "number", so setting the value to anything parseable as a number just sets the value to that numeric value, not the formatted one.